# Different balance

Tags: blockchain, etherscan

I have a wallet with a different balance on two different scanners.
The first https://www.blockchain.com/eth/address/0xbd25c14f148273ed2b28537d18ad550420329117?view=standard shows a balance of 0.7 ETH
The second https://etherscan.io/address/0xbd25c14f148273ed2b28537d18ad550420329117 shows only 0.015 ETH.
Who is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your balance is 0.015 ETH, as shown in Etherscan. [Blockchair](https://blockchair.com/ethereum/address/0xbd25c14f148273ed2b28537d18ad550420329117) shows the same balance. Also when querying `eth_getBalance()` via [Alchemy API](https://composer.alchemyapi.io/), we get 0.015 ETH too. Not sure why Blockchain.com shows a different value.